# Why doesn't my XMLStarlet query work when it includes quotes?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have this XML

```
<Result>
<Dataset name='ident1'>
 <Row name='a1'>
    <queryname>cat0</queryname>
    <superfilename>cat1</superfilename>
    <indexfilename>cat2</indexfilename>
</Row>
 <Row name='a2'>
    <queryname>cat3</queryname>
    <superfilename>cat4</superfilename>
    <indexfilename>cat5</indexfilename>
 </Row>
 <Row name='a3'>
    <queryname>cat6</queryname>
    <superfilename>cat7</superfilename>
    <indexfilename>cat8</indexfilename>
 </Row>
</Dataset>
<Dataset name='Result 2'>
</Dataset>
<Dataset name='Result 3'>
</Dataset>
<Dataset name='Result 4'>
</Dataset>
</Result>
```

**I want to count the number of rows of DataSet named ident1**. The xmlstarlet command I am using is:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1']/Row)' oscar.xml
```

I think it should work but it is returning 0.

I have tried other variations but all of them return 0.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1'])' oscar.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1'][*]/Row)' oscar.xml
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1']/Row[*])' oscar.xml
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

NOTE

If I count other element like DataSet it returns correctly 4.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/Result/Dataset)' oscar.xml
```

Comment: You're using the same quotes as shell syntax and xmlstarlet syntax.

Comment: ...btw, StackOverflow's syntax highlighting (though often wrong for shell) is actually something you might have taken as a useful hint in this case.

Comment: I use Notepad++ as editor with "batch" syntax. I should add "bash" syntax to avoid this...

Comment: I can't speak to the quality of Nodepad++'s bash highlighting, since I stick to vim (for bash, Python, Go, &c), emacs (for LISPs) and IntelliJ (for Java) myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this, the quotes are all shell syntax; in consequence, the shell strips the quotes before the query is given to XMLStarlet:

```
# bad: looks for @name=ident1, no quotes
# literal query is: count(/Result/Dataset[@name=ident1]/Row)
# ...which compares @name against the value of an element under Dataset named ident1
# ...since no such element exists, the result is a count of 0.
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1']/Row)' oscar.xml
```

Instead, make it:

```
# good: uses ""s on the outside, so ''s on the inside are literal
# literal query is: count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1']/Row)
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1']/Row)" oscar.xml
```

...or, if your shell is bash:

```
# good (but nonportable): uses $'' syntax, which makes \' produce a single literal '
# literal query is: count(/Result/Dataset[@name='ident1']/Row)
xmlstarlet sel -t -v $'count(/Result/Dataset[@name=\'ident1\']/Row)' oscar.xml
```

---

All the above happens because quotes, in shell, are a per-character characteristic. You can, for instance, write:

```
echo "$foo"'$bar'$baz
```

...and `$foo` will be expanded per double-quote rules (literal replacement with comments), `$bar` will be treated as a literal string, and `$baz` will be expanded per unquoted-expansion rules (with string-splitting and globbing resulting in oft-unwanted behaviors).

Comment: I use bash. I didn't realized about quotes. When I saw a 0 I thought syntax was right. Thanks :-)

Comment: One thing you can do to see how the shell is interpreting your syntax is to run `set -x`, which will print each command to stderr before running it. But, yeah, the result is a valid XPath query, it's just not one that does what you want.